# Pandas: How do you group data together by date and apply multiple functions to the grouped data?

Tags: python, pandas

In my code i have a pandas dataframe with a column for the day and a column called value. I would like to group the dataframe by day and find the minimum and maximum value for that day, average the min and max and then subtract that average from the value column in the dataframe.

The closest thing i have been able to do has been:

```
temp_max = var.groupby(['day']).max()
temp_min = var.groupby(['day']).min()

answer = var.groupby(['day'])['value'].apply(lambda x : x - (temp_max['value'] - temp_min['value']) / 2 )
```

**input:**

```
    Unnamed: 0  hrs                   vt                   rt      value
0       119899    1  2017-03-01 07:00:00  2017-03-01 06:00:00  67.910011
1       119900    2  2017-03-01 08:00:00  2017-03-01 06:00:00  52.970033
2       119901    3  2017-03-01 09:00:00  2017-03-01 06:00:00  49.010011
3       119902    4  2017-03-01 10:00:00  2017-03-01 06:00:00  47.030000
4       119903    5  2017-03-01 11:00:00  2017-03-01 06:00:00  45.949989
5       119904    6  2017-03-01 12:00:00  2017-03-01 06:00:00  45.949989
```

**output:**

```
1    0           NaN
 1     41.540022
 2     31.549989
 3     29.570005
 4     36.949989
 5     38.030000
 6     40.010011
 7     33.980000
 8     47.030000
 9           NaN
 10          NaN
 11          NaN
 12          NaN
 13          NaN
 14          NaN
 15          NaN
 16          NaN
2    1           NaN
     2           NaN
     3           NaN
     4           NaN
     5           NaN
     6           NaN
     7           NaN
     8           NaN
     17          NaN
     18          NaN
     19          NaN
     20          NaN
     21          NaN
             ...    
6    4           NaN
     5           NaN
     6           NaN
     7           NaN
     8           NaN
     53          NaN
     54          NaN
     55          NaN
     56          NaN
7    1           NaN
     2           NaN
     3           NaN
     4           NaN
     5           NaN
     6           NaN
     7           NaN
     8           NaN
     57          NaN
     58          NaN
     59          NaN
     60          NaN
8    1           NaN
     2           NaN
     3           NaN
     4           NaN
     5           NaN
     6           NaN
     7           NaN
     8           NaN
     61          NaN
```

The values appear to be correct but i was hoping to keep my original dataframe and just update the values in place. Is there a different way i should be approaching this? Thx in advance!

Comment: Can you show a sample of your input?

Comment: My bad! I added the input to the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
new_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=var.columns)

for day,frame in var.groupby('day'):

    frame.loc[:,'value'] = frame['value'].apply(lambda x: x - (frame.value.max() + frame.value.min())/2)

    new_frame = new_frame.append(frame)
```

You could do it in one line using a list comprehension and groupby but it looks a bit ugly

```
var.loc[:,'value'] = pd.concat([frm.value.apply(lambda x:x-(frm.value.min() + frm.value.max())/2) for d,frm in var.groupby('day')])
```

I believe that would accomplish what you're trying to do, albeit not being particularly readable!

Comment: that is nice because it allows me to skip the first 2 lines of code i have, but im still not sure of a way to apply the average of those values to the ['value'] column of the var dataframe cleanly.

Comment: Sorry, read your question a bit quickly - would that lambda solve your problem?

Comment: totally understandable, but it looks like you cant use the agg function that way. I'm getting a " raise Exception('Must produce aggregated value')
" error.

Comment: You're right and I see why, maybe this can't be done in one line - but have a look at my latest edit